# Intellij 2016.1.4 and React render() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, react-dom, intellij-idea-2016

I have a render method inside React component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import MediaService from "./service/MediaService";
import ComponentLifecycle = require("@types/react");
import DOMHelper from "../helpers/DOMHelper";

export default class PictureTaker extends React.Component implements ComponentLifecycle {
    // Not important

    render () {
        return (
          <article>
              <video id="ra-video">
                  Video not supported
              </video>
          </article>
        );
    }
}
```

It marks `id` as `attribute id is not allowed here`, but OK - I got it. I want to refactor code to extract `<video>` to another component:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <video id="ra-video">
                Video not supported
            </video>
        );
    }
}
```

But it brokes with message: `unresolved type video`. Here is how it looks like:
[image: Broken render() method]

Code for `VideoPlayer` is pasted from `PictureTaker`, and it suprised me. I have `React`:

[image: React imported in project]

And `React DOM`:

[image: React DOM]

inside `Settings / Languages and frameworks / Javascript / Libraries`. Do you see any mistakes made by me? Thank you in advance for every answer.

Answer (score -1):

Geez, I found a solution... I used `.ts` extension instead of `.tsx`. 
 It was `VideoPlayer.ts`, and should be `VideoPlayer.tsx`, my bad.

Comment: you can just delete the question, "typo/non-preproducible"

Comment: @pvg Maybe, but it is a chance for React rookies to made mistakes like mine, and it could prevent them for wasting a hour like I wasted.

Comment: There really isn't any chance of that any more than there's a chance of having _any_ typo repeated. That's why that flag exists.

Answer (score -1):

What is video? You will have to import video.js along with React.js to use